# Bootstrap grid divs next to each other

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-4

In a webshop, i am listing out products into col-md-3 class divs.
With this, in mobile view, the divs are under each other.

What i want, that when i am viewing on mobile device, i want 2 divs next to each other.

How can i do that? Use not just the col-md-3 class, and add a col-xs-6 class to the divs?

```html
<div class="col-md-3 col-xs-6">
  <span class="ribbon-ketsoros">Ingyenes<br>szállítás</span>
  <a href="https://domain.hu/termek/186/gigabyte-z370-aorus-gaming-7-op-alaplap" title="Gigabyte Z370 AORUS GAMING 7-OP alaplap" class="main_item_img_to_link">
    <img src="https://domain.hu/images/item/th-8888-28950.jpg" alt="Gigabyte Z370 AORUS GAMING 7-OP alaplap" class="img-responsive">
  </a>
  <h2 class="main_item_title"><a href="https://domain.hu/termek/186/gigabyte-z370-aorus-gaming-7-op-alaplap" title="Gigabyte Z370 AORUS GAMING 7-OP alaplap" class="main_item_title_to_link">Gigabyte Z370 AORUS GAMING 7-OP alaplap</a></h2>
  <span class="main_item_cikkszam">Cikkszám: 997872</span>
  <span class="main_item_kiszereles">Kiszerelés: Darab</span>
  <span class="main_item_kiszereles"><b>Készleten</b></span>
  <input type="hidden" value="1" id="MinimumOrder186"><span class="main_item_price_2">101.290 Ft,-</span>
  <span class="main_item_price_3">Akciós ár: 97.290 Ft,-</span><a href="https://domain.hu/termek/186/gigabyte-z370-aorus-gaming-7-op-alaplap" class="kiemeltek_to_link" title="Termék adatlap">Termék adatlap <i class="fa fa-info-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The example below will list 2 divs next to each other from extra small and up:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-6">
      <span class="ribbon-ketsoros">Ingyenes<br>szállítás</span>
      <a href="https://domain.hu/termek/186/gigabyte-z370-aorus-gaming-7-op-alaplap" title="Gigabyte Z370 AORUS GAMING 7-OP alaplap" class="main_item_img_to_link">
        <img src="https://domain.hu/images/item/th-8888-28950.jpg" alt="Gigabyte Z370 AORUS GAMING 7-OP alaplap" class="img-responsive">
      </a>
      <h2 class="main_item_title"><a href="https://domain.hu/termek/186/gigabyte-z370-aorus-gaming-7-op-alaplap" title="Gigabyte Z370 AORUS GAMING 7-OP alaplap" class="main_item_title_to_link">Gigabyte Z370 AORUS GAMING 7-OP alaplap</a></h2>
      <span class="main_item_cikkszam">Cikkszám: 997872</span>
      <span class="main_item_kiszereles">Kiszerelés: Darab</span>
      <span class="main_item_kiszereles"><b>Készleten</b></span>
      <input type="hidden" value="1" id="MinimumOrder186"><span class="main_item_price_2">101.290 Ft,-</span>
      <span class="main_item_price_3">Akciós ár: 97.290 Ft,-</span><a href="https://domain.hu/termek/186/gigabyte-z370-aorus-gaming-7-op-alaplap" class="kiemeltek_to_link" title="Termék adatlap">Termék adatlap <i class="fa fa-info-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
    </div>
    
    <div class="col-6">
      <span class="ribbon-ketsoros">Ingyenes<br>szállítás</span>
      <a href="https://domain.hu/termek/186/gigabyte-z370-aorus-gaming-7-op-alaplap" title="Gigabyte Z370 AORUS GAMING 7-OP alaplap" class="main_item_img_to_link">
        <img src="https://domain.hu/images/item/th-8888-28950.jpg" alt="Gigabyte Z370 AORUS GAMING 7-OP alaplap" class="img-responsive">
      </a>
      <h2 class="main_item_title"><a href="https://domain.hu/termek/186/gigabyte-z370-aorus-gaming-7-op-alaplap" title="Gigabyte Z370 AORUS GAMING 7-OP alaplap" class="main_item_title_to_link">Gigabyte Z370 AORUS GAMING 7-OP alaplap</a></h2>
      <span class="main_item_cikkszam">Cikkszám: 997872</span>
      <span class="main_item_kiszereles">Kiszerelés: Darab</span>
      <span class="main_item_kiszereles"><b>Készleten</b></span>
      <input type="hidden" value="1" id="MinimumOrder186"><span class="main_item_price_2">101.290 Ft,-</span>
      <span class="main_item_price_3">Akciós ár: 97.290 Ft,-</span><a href="https://domain.hu/termek/186/gigabyte-z370-aorus-gaming-7-op-alaplap" class="kiemeltek_to_link" title="Termék adatlap">Termék adatlap <i class="fa fa-info-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just having `col` grid class will stack the div's horizontally in all viewports. `Bootstrap` will automatically take care of partitioning the width equally. Take a look at [bootstrap documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/grid/#equal-width) on grid system for more info.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col"> <!--Col 1-->
      <span class="ribbon-ketsoros">Ingyenes<br>szállítás</span>
      <h2 class="main_item_title"><a href="https://domain.hu/termek/186/gigabyte-z370-aorus-gaming-7-op-alaplap"
                                     title="Gigabyte Z370 AORUS GAMING 7-OP alaplap" class="main_item_title_to_link">Gigabyte
        Z370 AORUS GAMING 7-OP alaplap</a></h2>
      <span class="main_item_cikkszam">Cikkszám: 997872</span>
      <span class="main_item_kiszereles">Kiszerelés: Darab</span>
      <span class="main_item_kiszereles"><b>Készleten</b></span>
    </div>

    <div class="col"> <!--Col 2-->
      <span class="ribbon-ketsoros">Ingyenes<br>szállítás</span>
      <h2 class="main_item_title"><a href="https://domain.hu/termek/186/gigabyte-z370-aorus-gaming-7-op-alaplap"
                                     title="Gigabyte Z370 AORUS GAMING 7-OP alaplap" class="main_item_title_to_link">Gigabyte
        Z370 AORUS GAMING 7-OP alaplap</a></h2>
      <span class="main_item_cikkszam">Cikkszám: 997872</span>
      <span class="main_item_kiszereles">Kiszerelés: Darab</span>
      <span class="main_item_kiszereles"><b>Készleten</b></span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I've created a [pen](https://codepen.io/SubSul/pen/dqqraL) as well with the above code, play around and check out the output.

Answer (score 0):

True, most of the bootstrap templates col- classes are used in a mixing way. So just add the col-xs-6 for the first div, col-xs-6 for the 2nd div (remember they should have a div class="row" wrap outside so that the col class may understand and divide ) , as a result, in mobile mode they'll stand next to each other. Hope this help (This code is only works if you're using Bootstrap v3.3.7, in Bootstrap 4 some col-classes are changed) :

```
 <div class="container">
    <div class="row"> <!-- 1 ROW = 12 COLUMNS OF GRID -->
    <!-- YOUR PRODUCTS LIST -->
       <!-- FIRST DIV-->
       <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-6 col-lg-3 col-sm-6">
        ... // THE CONTENT HERE
       </div>
       <!--SECOND DIV-->
       <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-6 col-lg-3 col-sm-6">
       </div>
    <!--END OF YOUR PRODUCTS LIST-->
    </div>
</div>
```

Note that a row contain the div is equal 12 columns, so when you use mixing like this :

```
 col-md-3 = 3/12 = 1/4 ( in larger desktop mode )
 col-xs-6 = 6/12 = 1/2 in mobile mode
 col-lg-3 = 3/12 = 1/4 ( in desktop mode )
 col-sm-6 = 6/12 = 1/2 in tablet mode
```